# Why does setuptools not create my entry points?

Tags: python, setuptools, entry-point

My project directory structure looks like this:

```
clc
 |-clc
 |  |-__init__.py
 |  |-clc.py
 |  |-main.py
 |-setup.py
```

`main.py` looks like this:

```
def main():
    print "it works!"
```

in `setup.py`:

```
config = {
    ...
    'entry_points':
        'clc_scripts': ['clc = clc.main:main']
    }
}
setup(**config)
```

When I run `python setup.py build`, I end up with the following:

```
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib
creating build/lib/clc
copying clc/__init__.py -> build/lib/clc
copying clc/clc.py -> build/lib/clc
copying clc/main.py -> build/lib/clc
```

No `bin` folder is created, even though I specified an entry point. It does create a file `clc.egg-info/entry_points.txt`:

```
$ cat clc.egg-info/entry_points.txt
[clc_scripts]
clc = clc.main:main
```

Why did setuptools not create my entry point executable file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1)** The entry point for generating scripts is called [`console_scripts`](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation).

So fix the name of the entry point in your `setup.py` like this:

```
config = {
    ...
    'entry_points':
        'console_scripts': ['clc = clc.main:main']
    }
}
```

**2)** [Entry points](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#dynamic-discovery-of-services-and-plugins) won't get executed when you just `build` your distribution. They really only make sense for `install` or `develop`. Try `python setup.py install`.

Comment: Aha, thanks. I thought I was supposed to pick my own entry point group names.

Strangely, this didn't seem to change much. `build` still produces the same output.

Comment: To clarify, after running `python setup.py build`, `entry_points.txt` now says `console_scripts` instead of `clc_scripts`. Still no `bin` folder is created.

Comment: I'm pretty sure entry points won't get executed when you just `build` your distribution. They really only make sense for `install` or `develop`. Try `python setup.py install`.

Comment: You're welcome. I rolled back your question to it's original form, otherwise the answer doesn't make sense any more. I'll update it accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Entry point scripts are created at install time, not build time, because they will need to point to the correct location of the installing python's interpreter.